# ¿Qué significa la expresión "como que"? / What does the phrase "como que" mean?

Tags: modismos, preposiciones

Leyendo un libro, encontré este pasaje:

> "¡Qué ocurrencias! Viera que yo estuviera vivo, ¡de tarugo mi iba a acercar a oír lo que dijera un muerto! **Como que** pensaría que los muertos no tienen nada que decir. Están
>   muertos pues. **Como que** su trabajo de los muertos es andar
>   espantando y no hablando. Yo me acuerdo que en mi tierra se decía que
>   los muertos que caminan todavía, es porque tienen algún pendiente y
>   por eso no están quietos. En mi tierra así se decía."
>
> -- *El fuego y la palabra: una historia del movimiento Zapatista*, Gloria Muñoz Ramírez

En este contexto, ¿qué significa la expresión "como que"? ¿Hay algún ejemplo que muestre cómo usarlo en otras situaciones?

Comment: Dejando aparte su significado, que ya se intenta explicar en las respuestas, yo no aconsejaría usar esta expresión. Este texto muestra un habla idiosincrática de una zona concreta y usa giros, como este, que pueden resultar chocantes en otros sitios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La RAE dice al respecto de las locuciones `como que` y `cómo que` que en el caso de ["como que"](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=s3kpSlOhuD6v706948):

> [*Como*] forma la locución conjuntiva *como que*, que tiene un **valor causal explicativo**:
>
> - Lo conozco muy bien, *como que* he sido su vecino durante veinte años.
>
> Con este mismo valor suele encabezar oraciones enfáticas de réplica:
>
> - —Tienes ojeras. —¡Como que llevo dos noches sin dormir!
>
> También se emplea la locución como que con **valor modal o atenuativo**:
>
> - El niño hace *como que* juega
> - Se sentía *como que* había caído en una trampa.

Además

> [*Como*] introduce oraciones exclamativas independientes de **valor enfático y sentido irónico**, contrario a su significado literal:
>
> - ¡Como para fiestas estoy yo ahora! [= no estoy para fiestas]
> - ¡**Como que me van a dejar mis padres! [= no me van a dejar mis padres]**.

De manera análoga, para la locución "cómo que"

> A veces se usa el adverbio exclamativo `cómo` seguido de la conjunción `que` para **expresar disconformidad o extrañeza ante lo expresado por el interlocutor**. En estos casos, la conjunción que se explica por la elisión del verbo decir:
>
> - ¡Cómo [dices] que no me entero!
> - ¡Cómo [dices] que no te ayude!
>
> Es frecuente esta construcción con la simple negación: ¡Cómo que no!

Answer (score 3):

Esto creo que es mexicano, en España este texto no tiene sentido, habría que trascribir completo. Aquí podría usarse "como si", pero como ya he dicho cambiándolo todo.

Ejemplo:

> ¿Me ayudas con el trabajo?
>
> **Como si** yo no tuviera ya bastante que hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Yo soy argentino, y esa locución en ese párrafo me resulta casi incomprensible.

Atendiendo a la lógica, creo que aquí *"como que"* debe leerse, no en sentido irónico, sino (según primera acepción en la respuesta de Diego) en sentido *"causal explicativo"*. Más o menos equivalente a *"puesto que"*, o *"dado que"* o *"porque"*.

En todo caso, no es un español muy correcto...

Añado que la locución *"como que"* ( o *"Es como que"*) tiene otro sentido (al menos en el habla informal de Argentina, sobre todo al comienzo de una frase). Matiza lo que sigue, como expresando que la expresión es aproximada: "las cosas son más o menos así:..." . Similar al *"It's like..."* en inglés.

[Por ejemplo](https://www.letras.com/los-chalchaleros/1297140/)

Para profundizar, [aquí hay un artículo](http://cvc.cervantes.es/ensenanza/biblioteca_ele/asele/pdf/12/12_0551.pdf) académico que estudia el asunto.

Answer (score 1):

Es locución mexicana por seguro, dado que el texto trata de la era Zapatista en México.  Este uso sumamente mexicano de esta expresión tiene analogía con la expresión "like" o "as if" en Inglés y parece no tener sentido porque en realidad es un fragmento de un enunciado que añade a la frase anterior. Esa pausa es muy reconocible para mí como el tono y pauta de una persona mexicana, posiblemente de procedencia rural, en parte porque así habla mi propia madre de vez en cuando.

Podría reinterpretarlo de la siguiente forma, en un Español más néutro:

> ¡Qué ocurrencias! Si yo estuviera vivo, yo no me acercaría a escuchar lo que tiene que decir un muerto. Sería muy tonto de mí.  Me haría de la idea que los muertos no tienen nada que decir, pues están muertos. Pienso que el trabajo de un muerto es espantar y no hablar. Me acuerdo que en mi tierra se decía que los muertos que caminan todavía, es porque tienen algún pendiente y es por eso que no descansan. Así se decía en mi tierra.

Answer (score 0):

**Tal como** dijo psosuna, es un coloquialismo.  Y, tal como yo utilizo "tal como", ésto es que significa "como que"